# JavaFX: how to check for anti-aliasing support

Tags: java, javafx-8

When creating a JavaFX Scene, I am passing in SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED as a parameter, but on my laptop it gives me this warning:

```
WARNING: System can't support antiAliasing
```

I'd like to know if there is any way of testing for this ability programmatically? There seems to be nothing under the javafx.application.ConditionalFeature checks that you can do on the Platform object. Anyone have any pointers on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best you can do is just check:

```
Platform.isSupported(ConditionalFeature.SCENE3D)
```

There is no explicit feature check for scene anti-aliasing.  The [scene anti-aliasing documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#Scene-javafx.scene.Parent-double-double-boolean-javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing-) refers to the [`SCENE3D` conditional feature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/ConditionalFeature.html#SCENE3D). I guess that it is possible for `SCENE3D` to be supported while scene anti-aliasing is not (though I would think that would be quite a rare combination). I think that if `SCENE3D` is supported but scene anti-aliasing is not, it would seem that most applications would want to display the 3D scene anyway, just without anti-aliasing, which I think is how JavaFX would handle this.  The potential warning output to the command line is slightly annoying, but probably not a deal breaker for most apps.

Comment: Should (now) be "SCENE3D"  (without underscore).  (See DOCS)